# Having Trouble Centring Content Vertically In Sections

Tags: javascript, css, html

Sorry, if there's not enough detail in this initial post, my web-development skills are relatively limited, so I'm working with a web developer, if you need any extra information though, it shouldn't be a problem getting hold of it, and any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Our site is using sections as opposed to pages, and the problem we're having is getting the content to centre vertically in each section. Obviously this has to be dynamic based on the user's resolution: 
http://demo.ekarsh.com/crimsonnight/assets/js/KamiDrop_v1.8/index.html.
The site is built using a combination of HTML5 and Javascript.

Once again, any advice would be appreciated as the site's not really usable until this has been fixed! Thanks :)

Comment: We need to see some code and ideally a working example in something like codepen or jsfiddle. This can assist other users in answering your question. Without any code, it's hard to help.

Comment: What has to be centered related to what? I can see the status quo but not how it's supposed to look like. Moreover a question has to include _the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem_. As a side note: The white text isn't readable and It's not a good idea having to chase links.

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for your comments, sorry, it's my first post here!
Every section should snap to the user's screen, the content of each section should then be in the centre of that section. At the moment the content of each section is in the horizontal centre, but not the vertical, instead being close to the top. I have posted the code used in a comment below, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Without any code it's hard to help but I would take a look at something like: http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/

You will probably have some other problems when the content is taller than the browser size but with some media queries, and possibly some JavaScript, this can be solves as well.

Good luck!

Comment: Hey there, thanks a lot for your suggestion, the developer I'm working with has tried implementing it and says the following:

I have this type of structure.

`<section id="about1" class="panel overview " data-section-name="about">
<div class="aboutsectionbackground">
..................
</div>
</section>`

The section height is same as screen height - as the screen resolution changes it changes.

Comment: As suggested I have applied the following css but the section goes more to the bottom, and if I try to reduce the 'top' property then it's not vertically in the middle for all resolutions. Can you please suggest a way around this?

`.aboutsectionbackground {
    position: relative !important;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%) !important;
 -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
}`

Comment: @CrimsonNight Can you please send a link to where this is implemented?

Comment: Thanks PP, of course, it's http://crimsonnight.com/kamigami/, although I have started a second thread as this one wasn't getting any responses: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31538913/having-trouble-centring-content-vertically-in-sections-updated