# Having Trouble Centring Content Vertically In Sections (Updated)

Tags: javascript, css, html

I did post this question yesterday, but don't think I included enough info, so have re-written it based on the previous comments - apologies (I'm new here) so thanks for any help offered. The site's not really usable until this has been fixed so I'm very keen to get it sorted!

(I'm working with a developer on this site as my skills are a little lacking.)
Our site is using sections as opposed to pages. Every section should snap to the user's screen, the content of each section should then be in the centre of that section. The problem we're having is that at the moment the content of each section is in the horizontal centre, but not the vertical, instead being closer to the [top](http://demo.ekarsh.com/crimsonnight/assets/js/KamiDrop_v1.8/index.html). Obviously this needs to be dynamic based on the user's resolution. The site is built using a combination of HTML5, Javascript and CSS; this is the current structure:

```
<section id="about1" class="panel overview " data-section-name="about">    
  <div class="aboutsectionbackground"> .................. </div> 
</section>
```

We have tried the code featured [here](http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/) as previously suggested, but the content moves closer to the bottom, and if we try to reduce the 'top' property then it's not vertically in the middle for all resolutions. Can you please suggest a way around this?

```css
.aboutsectionbackground {
  position: relative !important;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%) !important;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

As I said, any help is greatly appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: What CSS code you are applying to `<section>` tag?

Comment: How do you realise the "snapping" and what does the body and CSS around said section look like? Can you provide an exact fiddle or pen of the problem? Would make it a lot easier to solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

try position absolute which would fix it based on the position of ancestor element.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. I have applied the 'position:absolute' property and also the 'top' property to align it to the center but the same problem occurs - it's not vertically aligned correctly for all resolutions and it also ruins all responsive design of that div

Answer (score 0):

use `display:table-cell` in the parent div, and `vertical-align:middle` on the child element.

Answer (score 0):

theres a way to get your content to always display in the middle vertically using a simple hack without the need for position fixed/absolute etc...

all you need is a container. Inside this container you put 2 `elements (div or section)` and give them `display: inline-block` and `vertical-align: middle`

one of these is the "hack" div, which will have height of 100%, the other will just be your content. Since they both have vertical align middle, and one of them is 100% height, the other will always snap into the middle of the section vertically.

see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pcgcrmsw/

this way you don't worry about the height of any of your content, this will put the content in the middle automatically for you without caring what dimensions the content has

Comment: Hi Abdul,

Thanks a lot for the hack, I've implemented it on my site, but it only really seems to be working correctly for the first section, the others loose their horizontal alignment and also the content gets pushed towards the bottom of the screen when viewed on lower resolutions - do you have any idea how to combat this? I noticed there is no 'horizontal-align' css function. Here's the updated version of the site with your code implimented to most sections: http://crimsonnight.com/kamigami/#home

Thanks again! :)

Comment: @CrimsonNight its hard to know the exact cause without seeing the html/css. if you can make a fiddle I can see the code and make changes to it to update it.

Comment: I've updated the fiddle page (inc sidebar code) but it's going to be hard to see what's going on without the assets really though isn't it? http://jsfiddle.net/pcgcrmsw/1/

It may be easier just to view the source code on the actual page?

Comment: updated link: http://crimsonnight.com/kamigami/kamidrop/#home

@Abdul the site's getting close to being use-able so i'm looking forward to hearing back from you :)

Comment: @CrimsonNight Sorry been busy. I'll look at it in a bit

Comment: @CrimsonNight your html is very messy. I don't think you should have `div` tags inside of `a` tags. And you have places with inline styling and placing without inline styling. You need to keep the html/css as clean and readable as possible. look at this example site I made for you, with minimal html/css you can create styles that are reusable: http://jsfiddle.net/vjzqqv9s/1/